# Can exhaust system hangers make a car sound significantly different?

Tags: exhaust

Civic coupe vti 1999.

I previously had an accident after where my low suspension car fell to the ground at low speed when a wheel nut cane off.

After this the car didn’t sound as vibrant and peppy as before.  Nobody could figure out what was wrong or different.

Anyway today I today the exhaust was hitting the ground and we noticed one exhaust system hanger had completely ripped off and one was missing.  We replaced the hangers and car did improve in sound quality however this could be related to another repair which was happening in parallel which I will ask about seperately.

Could the sound difference have been caused by low hanging exhaust?  The problem is ever since the crash nobody had picked up on any exhaust defect or so am thinning might the rubber have just stretched after the accidenT?

The sound is better now and maybe it was caused adding the exhaust hangers(though I could be completely wrong about this as other repairs going on).

The sound is also not exactly as it used to be so something still needs improving.

Can the low hanging exhaust/worn/torn exhaust system hanger cause significant change in sound and is there anything I should look/am missing eg more hangers, exhaustsshould be completely level etc to see if I can improve the sound more other than exhaust leaks?

Thanks.

Comment: More likely your exhaust was bent or something wasn't sealing properly when the exhaust was partially attached.

Comment: @D.SM you are right it was bent.  What do you mean by ‘not sealing properly when the exhaust was partially attached’? Do u mean there is a leak at exhaust connection points?  Thanks.